# extract row with max value

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle, rdbms

I run this query:

```
SELECT
    orderid AS "id", MAX(streamSeq) AS "mxseq", fillQty AS "execQty"
FROM 
    matchit_uat.matchit_messages o
WHERE 
    (o.date >= to_timestamp(1463630400)) AND 
    (o.date <= to_timestamp(1463702400)) AND 
    orderid= 2001231
GROUP BY 
    orderId, fillQty
```

..and get the result:

```
id      mxseq       execQty
2001231 212438879   (null)
2001231 212439080   1012
```

I now want to extract the row with the maximum `mxseq`. How can I do that?

Comment: How is this mysql and oracle?

Comment: Use "Order by 2" (if it's TSQL) and use TOP 1?

Comment: Maximum over what? Over all id and execQty combinations? The max over all max'es is the max of the original set - why is this not the same as select `max(streamseq) from matchit_uat.matchit_messages where ... ` ? Or did you want the maximum mxseq for each id? Or what?

Answer (score 0):

Use a derived table to get the max streamSeq per orderid and `join` the result to the original table. `group by` fillQty isn't required.

```
SELECT t.id, t.mxstreamSeq, o.fillQty AS "execQty"
FROM matchit_uat.matchit_messages o
JOIN (select orderid AS "id", MAX(streamSeq) AS "mxstreamSeq" 
      from matchit_uat.matchit_messages
      group by orderid) t 
ON t.id = o.orderid and t.mxstreamSeq = o.streamSeq
WHERE o.date >= to_timestamp(1463630400) 
AND o.date <= to_timestamp(1463702400) 
AND o.orderid = 2001231
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle 12c+, you would use the ANSI standard syntax:

```
SELECT orderid AS "id", MAX(streamSeq) AS "mxseq", fillQty AS "execQty"
FROM matchit_uat.matchit_messages o
WHERE (o.date >= to_timestamp(1463630400)) AND 
      (o.date <= to_timestamp(1463702400)) AND 
      orderid = 2001231
GROUP BY orderId, fillQty
ORDER BY MAX(streamSeq) DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

In MySQL, you would replace the last line with `LIMIT 1`.

In earlier versions of Oracle, you can use a subquery and `where rownum = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
SELECT
    orderid AS "id", MAX(streamSeq) OVER (PARTITION BY orderId, fillQty) mxseq, fillQty AS "execQty"
FROM 
    matchit_uat.matchit_messages o
WHERE 
    (o.date >= to_timestamp(1463630400)) AND 
    (o.date <= to_timestamp(1463702400)) AND 
    orderid= 2001231
```

for more info see oracle link : 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174